# Is this a case of free indirect speech?

Tags: grammaticality, meaning-in-context, speech

I would like to know if Rowling uses the technique of [free indirect speech](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_indirect_speech) in this piece of Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets, particularly in the italicized part.

> Harry was silent. Judging by the fact that Draco Malfoy usually had the best of everything, his family was rolling in wizard gold; *he could just see Malfoy strutting around a large manor house. Sending the family servant to stop Harry going back to Hogwarts also sounded exactly like the sort of thing Malfoy would do. Had Harry been stupid to take Dobby seriously?*

Comment: I don't see speech, but Harry is imagining a scene:  He could just *see* Malfoy strutting around.

Comment: Perhaps you need to read up on narrative techniques. The text is not spoken English.

Comment: You might try asking at https://literature.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Ask your teacher.

Comment: It seems that the last sentence is "free indirect speech," but that's a literary rather than linguistic term.

Comment: 'Harry was silent. Had he been stupid to take Dobby seriously?' shows a self-directed mental question. Replacing 'he' with 'Harry' may be clumsy (at best) here, but is necessary after 3½ intervening lines, which padding also makes what would be a jarring juxtaposition quite acceptable. But you fail to add a definition of 'free indirect speech', as @Andy says, a specialised literary term (if it's idiomatic in that domain).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I hadn't heard of it before, but [it seems it's a thing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_indirect_speech). And yes, that the final sentence qualifies. And it's clearly more at home in literary criticism (though tbh I'm not sure whether maybe its linguistic features could make it on-topic here, or at least more substantive questions of "how" rather than "whether").

Comment: @Andy Yes, I'd say it stands alongside direct and indirect speech, which nobody would say are off-topic. I've voted to re-open even though OP omitted necessary research (the examples from Wikipedia, especially). Worth keeping (and therefore editing ... which possibly self-answers).

Answer (score 1):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_indirect_speech) [adjusted]:

**Free indirect speech** is a style of third-person narration which uses some of the characteristics of third-person along with the essence of first-person direct speech.

It is also referred to as free indirect discourse, free indirect style, or, in French, discours indirect libre.

Free indirect speech has been described as a "technique of presenting a character's voice partly mediated by the voice of the author" (or, reversing the emphasis, "that the character speaks through the voice of the narrator") with the voices effectively merged. It has also been described as "the illusion by which third-person narrative comes to express ... the intimate subjectivity of fictional characters."  The word "free" in the phrase is used to capture the fact that with this technique, the author can "roam from viewpoint to viewpoint" instead of being fixed with one character or with the narrator.

According to British philologist Roy Pascal, Goethe and Jane Austen were the first novelists to use this style consistently, and 19th-century French novelist Flaubert was the first to be aware of it as a [distinct] style.

**Distinguishing marks of the technique**

Free indirect speech is characterized by these features:

- The lack of an introductory expression such as "he said" or "he thought". It is as if the subordinate clause carrying the content of the indirect speech were taken out of the main clause which contains it, becoming the main clause itself.
- Free indirect speech can convey the character's words more directly than in normal indirect speech. Devices such as interjections and psycho-ostensive expressions like curses and swearwords can be used that cannot be normally used within a subordinate clause. When deictic pronouns and adverbials are used, they refer to the coordinates of the originator of the speech or thought, not of the narrator.
- "The anomalous presence within third-person, past-tense narrative of linguistic features indicating a character's perspective and voice."
- Backshifted exclamations, such as, "How differently did every thing now appear in which he was concerned", an example from Pride and Prejudice.
- Unshifted modals, such as, "She must own that she was tired of great houses", also from Pride and Prejudice.
- Exclamatory questions, character-specific locutions and syntactical informalities and fragments.

Free indirect discourse can be described as a "technique of presenting a character's voice partly mediated by the voice of the author", or, in the words of the French narrative theorist Gérard Genette, "the narrator takes on the speech of the character, or, if one prefers, the character speaks through the voice of the narrator, and the two instances then are merged".

.............

Following are examples that use direct, indirect and free indirect speech:

- **Quoted or direct speech**: He laid down his bundle and thought of his misfortune. "And just what pleasure have I found, since I came into this world?" he asked.
- **Reported or normal indirect speech**: He laid down his bundle and thought of his misfortune. He asked himself what pleasure he had found since he came into the world.
- **Free indirect speech**: He laid down his bundle and thought of his misfortune. And just what pleasure had he found, since he came into this world?

.............

So as Andy Bonner has said, the last sentence in the Rowling extract is indeed in the 'free indirect speech' style, though unusually the expected pronoun ('he' here) must be replaced by the antecedent ('Harry') after 3½ intervening lines, making it less personal, less natural-sounding than is usual (see the Wikipedia example, which is more typical).